# What is the best sensor for the measurement of Carbon-dioxide?

Tags: sensors, hardware, arduino

I need to measure the amount of carbon-dioxide in parts per million (ppm) within a closed environment. Currently, I am using a MQ-135 gas sensor which has some sort of concentration on Carbon-dioxide. Unfortunately, that sensor does not provide accurate values.

What gas sensor can I get to obtain precise data?

The cost should not be more than USD 30. The MQ-135 has a very slight concentration on CO². The value it returns has a high fluctuation rate. Within the difference of seconds the value changes from 450 ppm to 700 ppm. I want a digital sensor that should give accurate data like Carbon Dioxide Meter PCE-WMM 50.

Comment: Please keep it civil in the comments. There's a voting system to determine if a question is on-topic or not. Decisions that don't fit your own interpretation of the site scope can be discussed on meta. They are not to be discussed in the comments on single questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Air Quality Sensor** : [*ams IAQ-CORE C*](http://ams.com/eng/Products/Environmental-Sensors/Air-Quality-Sensors/iAQ-core-C)

The iAQ-Core sensor module is used to measure VOC levels and provide CO² equivalent and TVOC equivalent predictions. It can measure 450 to 2,000 ppm CO² equivalents. It has a dimension of 15.24 x 17.78 mm. The data is available via I²C bus.

**Key Benefits**

1. Direct correlation to CO² and TVOC levels
2. High sensitivity and fast response
3. Micro size for convenient installation
4. Long-term stability
5. Low power consumption

**Applications :** Smart Home, Internet of Things, HVAC, Thermostats

**Personal Review :** Fluctuation rate is very low. Data is very accurate and precise. It is possible to integrate this sensor with Arduino, NodeMCU and Intel Edison.

**Implementation** : [Arduino library](https://github.com/maarten-pennings/iAQcore) for the iAQ-core indoor air quality sensor module with I2C interface from ams. The code has been tested with NodeMCU(ESP8266), Arduino pro mini and Arduino nano.

Answer (score 3):

**Sensor Used:** MH-Z19 CO² Sensor.
It is a common type, small size sensor, using non dispersive infrared (NDIR) principle to detect the existence of CO² in the air, with good selectivity, non-oxygen dependent and long life.

**Output Modes:** UART and PWM wave
I personally find this useful and used the same in a project. Also you can take help of the following github [link](https://github.com/TD-er/NodeMCU_PCB) to setup with NodeMCU.

Details of the sensor can be found [in this user manual (PDF).](http://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Infrared%20Gas%20Sensor/NDIR%20CO2%20SENSOR/MH-Z19%20CO2%20Ver1.0.pdf)